# Leyden jar-How does the storing process work?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

We can view the [Leyden jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) as a capacitor and a dielectric (glass). When the metal parts are charged thus is due to influence in the dielectric a counter electric field to be found.When we separate the metal parts the outer field disappears and to my understanding the glass should not be charged since we now have no outer electric field to cause influence in the glass. However, it is to be seen that after grounding the metal parts and returning them the charge is still there on the dielectric. Why? Why did not the dipoles just rearrange themselves, to the original positions after the outer electric field disappeared?

Suppose we understood why the charge on the glasbody is kept. How come does handling this glasbody not result in discharging it?

Comment: Bump the question up